# Fast rendering of canvas made of square grid

Tags: android, canvas

I am trying to generate a grid of squares using Android's canvas, here's the code:

```
    public static void drawSquares(Canvas canvas) {

        int canvasWidth = canvas.getWidth();
        int canvasHeight = canvas.getHeight();

        int squareWidth = canvasWidth / NUMBER_OF_HORIZONTAL_SQUARES;
        int squareHeight = canvasHeight / NUMBER_OF_VERTICAL_SQUARES;
        Rect destinationRect = new Rect();

        int xOffset;
        int yOffset;

        // Init paint
        Paint background = new Paint();

        // Set the destination rectangle size
        destinationRect.set(0, 0, squareWidth, squareHeight);

        for (int horizontalPosition = 0; horizontalPosition < NUMBER_OF_HORIZONTAL_SQUARES; horizontalPosition++){

            xOffset = horizontalPosition * squareWidth;

            for (int verticalPosition = 0; verticalPosition < NUMBER_OF_VERTICAL_SQUARES; verticalPosition++){

                yOffset = verticalPosition * squareHeight;

                // Set the destination rectangle offset for the canvas origin
                destinationRect.offsetTo(xOffset, yOffset);

                // color
                Random r = new Random();
                background.setColor(COLORS[r.nextInt(3)]);

                // draw
                canvas.drawRect(destinationRect, background );
            }
        }

    }
```

The following code takes 200ms to generate the grid, is there any way to get below 66ms mean? In this scenario the colours are fed randomly, but normally I'd pass the values externally via int array.

Thanks, for any help!

Comment: `The following code takes 200ms to generate the grid` - based on a specific device, this will undoubtably vary depending on every device.  Don't create new local variables every time this method is called, use instance variables where you can, for instance if horizontal and vertical are both 10 you create 100 new `Random` objects everytime this method is called.  This has a Quadratic time complexity (O(n^2)), this will never scale well.

Comment: Hey, already got rid of that, also disabled antiAliasing in Paint instance and dither. It is much better now, but still want to get to 30 fps.